# Is there a better way to count passed time without putting thread to sleep

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am looking at the code written by my colleague:

```
long tim = DateTime.Now.Ticks;// get current time in ticks
long startWait = tim + TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * 15; // add 15 seconds (in ticks) to current time

while ((tim < startWait) & !_myReader.ReaderOpen) //_myReader.ReaderOpen is external device
{  
    Thread.Sleep(100); // sleep for 100ms
    tim = DateTime.Now.Ticks; 
}
```

For some reason, this code does not look right. It seems like putting thread to sleep and waking it up every 100ms is huge waste of CPU.

Comment: Thread.Sleep should not use CPU.

Comment: Just check the time when you start your action and the time when you end your action and determine the difference?

Comment: @KSdev He doesn't know how long it will be until the reader is open.

Comment: @Fredou Although it does consume a thread, preventing it from doing anything else.  It also consumes CPU to be continually waking it back up to just to kick the back of the seat and ask, "Are we there yet," instead of waiting to be told when we're there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Timer` to execute periodically without forcing a thread to be sitting around doing nothing for the duration of that time.  it's also possible that the reader that you're using exposes some means of notifying you when things happen so that you can respond to those events without needing to poll the object.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `_myReader` doesn't provide any events. I will check out `Timer` class.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like this which is exactly the same thing but different

at least you can stop the loop when `myReader.ReaderOpen` become true, if the 100ms is important to you

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int TimeToWait = 15;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var mnu = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            while (sw.Elapsed.Seconds <= TimeToWait)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                mnu.WaitOne(100);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```